# Working in Mathematica over a cyclotomic ring

Tags: algebraic-manipulation

How can I simplify expressions in $\mathbb Q[x]/(x^7-1)$ in Mathematica, i.e. make Mathematica transform $x^{20}+x^8+x+3$ into $x^6+2x+3$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
PolynomialMod[x^20 + x^8 + x + 3, x^7 - 1]
```

> `3 + 2 x + x^6`.